# type '(String, List<Class>) => void' is not a subtype of type '(String, List<dynamic>) => void'

Tags: flutter, dart, generics

My goal is to have a sortable list widget. This list should be able to handle multiple types of objects. To do so, I've tried using generics in the widget definition.

Let's say I have those two sample classes :

```dart
class ClassA {
  ClassA({required this.name});

  final String name;
}

class ClassB extends ClassA {
  ClassB({required name, required this.value}) : super(name: name);

  final String value;
}
```

Here is the widget with the unrelated parts omitted :

```dart
class FilteredList<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  FilteredList({Key? key,
    // ... //
    required this.allObjects,
    required this.sortCallback})
      : super(key: key);

  // ... //
  final List<T> allObjects;
  final void Function(String sortBy, List<T> objects) sortCallback;

  @override
  _FilteredListState createState() => _FilteredListState();
}

class _FilteredListState<T> extends State<FilteredList<T>> {
  late String _dropdownValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(children: [
            // ... //,
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
              child: DropdownButton<String>(
                value: _dropdownValue,
                onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    _dropdownValue = newValue!;
                  });
                  widget.sortCallback(newValue!, widget.allObjects);
                },
                items: widget.dropdownItems
                    .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((option) =>
                    DropdownMenuItem(value: option, child: Text(option)))
                    .toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ]),
          Expanded(// ... //),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I wanted with this design to be able to instanciate a `FilteredList<ClassB>` widget and give it a `sortCallback` like this to tell it how to handle `ClassB` sorting :

```dart
void _sort(String sortBy, List<ClassB> list) {
    if (sortBy == "A") {
      list.sort((a, b) => a.name.compareTo(b.name));
    } else {
      list.sort((a, b) => b.name.compareTo(a.name));
    }
  }
```

Unfortunately, even if `a` and `b` are recognized at compile time as `ClassB` ojects, I get this error when updating the value of the `DropdownButton` :

```
Unhandled Exception: type '(String, List<ClassB>) => void' is not a
subtype of type '(String, List<dynamic>) => void'
```

Is there a way to achieve my goal or am I going the wrong way ?

Comment: While waiting for specific answers, I’m guessing the logic behind the rules of generic Lists and inheritance probably carry across languages, so you might find something useful from this Java question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po

Comment: @racraman Thank you for the link, I was afraid that it was the problem. I guess I'll have to make a widget per class.

Comment: `FilteredList<T>.createState` returns a `_FilteredListState`, which is shorthand for `_FilteredListState<dynamic>`, but presumably you want it to return a `_FilteredListState<T>`.  If fixing that doesn't help, please show where you attempt to pass `_sort` as a callback. (Or better yet, please provide a minimal, reproducible example.)

Comment: @racraman Dart would consider `List<Derived>` to be a subtype of `List<Base>` if `Derived` derives from `Base`.

Comment: @jamesdlin I overlooked this method, that was the fix. You have no idea of how much you saved me. Should I close the question or do you want to add an answer ?